# Typescript SetAttribute Error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When i execute a JS code in typescript, i get the following error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of
>   null

But It works perfectly in JS without any errors.

```
<HTML>
<path id="border" transform="translate(125, 125)"  style="stroke:white; marker-end:url(#InverseSemicircleEnd);"/>
</HTML>

TS:
document.getElementById("border").setAttribute("style",dec);
```

But not sure, why it results in error on TS. I also tried to change the name of the property for this ID, but no luck. Can some one help me in explaining on what i'm doing wrong here.

Thanks For your support
Regards
Suresh

Comment: Where is the TS code? Please post the whole component to see how the stuff is related.

Comment: Looks like you are calling it before the HTML is rendered

Comment: @JuanMendes: Yes that's what happening. Thanks for pointing that out..

Answer (score 1):

Because `document.getElementById` [could return `null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), you need to check if it is different from null.

```
const myEl = document.getElementById("border");
if (myEl !== null) {
  myEl.setAttribute("style",dec);
}
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("border")?.setAttribute("style",dec);
```

If you are sure that the element is defined and you want to avoid the check, use the [`!`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#:%7E:text=Non%2Dnull%20assertion%20operator&text=post%2Dfix%20expression%20operator%20may,with%20null%20and%20undefined%20excluded.) (Non-null assertion) operator:

```
document.getElementById("border")!.setAttribute("style",dec);
```

Make sure that the browser has loaded before querying elements because not doing so could lead to a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following way to solve :

```js
  hideDesPan(){
    let pan = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('showPan'));
    pan.style.display = "none";
  }
```